# How can i scrape next page data with python if next page load with java script, no URL change?

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping

I am trying to **scrape** a webpage using python. I have scraped 1st page successfully but I am unable to go to the next page because the next page URL is the same and next page is loading with javascript.

```
import requests
import bs4 as bs

url ='https://scamalert.sg/scam-details'
r = requests.get(url)
htmlcontent = r.content
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(htmlcontent, 'html.parser')

for tag in soup.find_all('h4',{"class":"card-title"}):
    print (tag.text)
```

[Website HTML][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zV9y.png

<a class-"page-1ink" href- "javascriptivoid (0) " onclick-"pagingOnCli ck('2') ">2

== 0

Comment: you need to use ```Selenium``` in this case

Comment: Sir, can you please suggest any example?

Comment: Did you try the script below @vpnkumar? What's the feedback?

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the ways you can get all the stories and their concerning links to the details page traversing all the next pages from that site. If you consider checking the chrome dev tools, you will notice that post http requests are made to this url `https://scamalert.sg/scam-details/GetStoryListAjax/` along with appropriate parameters to populate json content from which you can extract the desired fields.

```
import json
import requests

base = 'https://scamalert.sg{}'
link = 'https://scamalert.sg/scam-details/GetStoryListAjax/'

payload = {
    'scamType': '',
    'year': '',
    'month': '',
    'sortBy': 'Latest'
}

page = 1
while True:
    payload['page'] = page
    r = requests.post(link,data=payload)
    items = json.loads(r.json()['result'])['StoryList']
    if len(items)<=1:break
    for item in items:
        print(item['Title'],base.format(item['Url']))

    page+=1
```